# calculate time difference pandas dataframe

Tags: python, datetime, time, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe where index is as follows :

```
Index([16/May/2013:23:56:43, 16/May/2013:23:56:42, 16/May/2013:23:56:43, ..., 17/May/2013:23:54:45, 17/May/2013:23:54:45, 17/May/2013:23:54:45], dtype=object)
```

I have calculated time difference in consequent occurrences in the following method.

```
df2['tvalue'] = df2.index
df2['tvalue'] = np.datetime64(df2['tvalue'])
df2['delta'] = (df2['tvalue']-df2['tvalue'].shift()).fillna(0)
```

So I got following output

```
    Time                      tvalue delta                                          
16/May/2013:23:56:43   2013-05-01 13:23:56 00:00:00  
16/May/2013:23:56:42   2013-05-01 13:23:56 00:00:00  
16/May/2013:23:56:43   2013-05-01 13:23:56 00:00:00  
16/May/2013:23:56:43   2013-05-01 13:23:56 00:00:00  
16/May/2013:23:56:48   2013-05-01 13:23:56 00:00:00  
16/May/2013:23:56:48   2013-05-01 13:23:56 00:00:00  
16/May/2013:23:56:48   2013-05-01 13:23:56 00:00:00  
16/May/2013:23:57:44   2013-05-01 13:23:57 00:00:01  
16/May/2013:23:57:44   2013-05-01 13:23:57 00:00:00  
16/May/2013:23:57:44   2013-05-01 13:23:57 00:00:00
```

But it has calculated time difference taking the year as hours and the date is also different?What can be the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing your date was non-trivial, I think strptime could prob do it, but didn't work for me. Your example above your times are just strings, not datetimes.

```
In [140]: from dateutil import parser

In [130]: def parse(x):
   .....:     date, hh, mm, ss = x.split(':')
   .....:     dd, mo, yyyy = date.split('/')
   .....:     return parser.parse("%s %s %s %s:%s:%s" % (yyyy,mo,dd,hh,mm,ss))
   .....: 

In [131]: map(parse,idx)
Out[131]: 
[datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 16, 23, 56, 43),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 16, 23, 56, 42),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 16, 23, 56, 43),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 17, 23, 54, 45),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 17, 23, 54, 45),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 17, 23, 54, 45)]

In [132]: pd.to_datetime(map(parse,idx))
Out[132]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2013-05-16 23:56:43, ..., 2013-05-17 23:54:45]
Length: 6, Freq: None, Timezone: None

In [133]: df = DataFrame(dict(time = pd.to_datetime(map(parse,idx))))

In [134]: df
Out[134]: 
                 time
0 2013-05-16 23:56:43
1 2013-05-16 23:56:42
2 2013-05-16 23:56:43
3 2013-05-17 23:54:45
4 2013-05-17 23:54:45
5 2013-05-17 23:54:45

In [138]: df['delta'] = (df['time']-df['time'].shift()).fillna(0)

In [139]: df
Out[139]: 
                 time     delta
0 2013-05-16 23:56:43  00:00:00
1 2013-05-16 23:56:42 -00:00:01
2 2013-05-16 23:56:43  00:00:01
3 2013-05-17 23:54:45  23:58:02
4 2013-05-17 23:54:45  00:00:00
5 2013-05-17 23:54:45  00:00:00
```

Comment: Could also use `df.diff()` instead of `df['time'] - df['time'].shift()`.  A bit cleaner.

Comment: @Jeff : Worked Perfectly! :) But it takes time to process the code!